# Swagger UI not displaying Model details on Swagger UI in .NET 6

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have below swagger code and model class. My other models can be seen on Swagger UI. Only this one is missing and not sure why and what I am missing here. I am using this model in controller code in catch block to return errors. Still its having an issue.

```
//Swagger.cs file
public static class SwaggerConfig
    {
        public static void ConfigureSwaggerServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "API",
                    Version = "v1",
                    Description = "APIs."
                });

                // Set the comments path for the Swagger xml and UI.
                var xmlCommentsFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlCommentsFile);

                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
                c.IncludeXmlComments($@"{System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}/Models.xml");

            });
        }

        public static void ConfigureSwaggerMiddleware(this WebApplication app)
        {
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()|| Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ENVIRONMENT") =="Dev")
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.yaml", "API V1");
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Model class file is as below.

```
public class ErrorList
    {
        public ErrorList()
        {
            Errors = new List<Errors>();
        }

        public List<Errors> Errors { get; set; } 
    }
```